# Showing change in value based on time interval

Tags: sql

I currently have a set of data that looks as such:

```
year  quarter  revenue
2018  Q1       100
2018  Q2       200
2018  Q3       300
2018  Q4       400
2019  Q1       300
2019  Q2       800
2019  Q3       1000
2019  Q4       2000
```

I'm looking to create an output that looks like this

```
yr_quarter  yty_growth
2018-Q1     NULL
2018-Q2     NULL
2018-Q3     NULL
2018-Q4     NULL
2019-Q1     200%
2019-Q2     300%
2019-Q3     233%
2019-Q4     400%
```

What would be the best way to replicate the output posted above based on the original data?

Comment: "Best" is a bit subjective - can you define what "*best*" would be in your context? Is it speed? Efficiency? Reliability? What have you tried so far to implement this requirement, and where *specifically* are you getting stuck? Can you tag the RDBMS you're using?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
SELECT c1.* , (c1.revenue-c2.revenue)*100.0 /c2.revenue yty_growth
FROM  tableName c1
LEFT JOIN tableName c2
ON c1.year = c2.year + 1 
AND c1.quarter = c2.quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

Window Function works in these type of problems. LAG() which uses the previous value of a partition.

```
   SELECT 
     CAST([YEAR] as VARCHAR(100)) +'-' + [QUARTER] AS [Yr-Quarter]
     , (  Revenue-   LAG(Revenue,1 ) OVER (PARTITION  by [QUARTER] order by Year ) ) * 
    100 / 
     LAG(Revenue,1 ) OVER (PARTITION  by [QUARTER] order by Year ) AS pre_Revenue 
 FROM REVENUE
  ORDER BY  [Yr-Quarter]
```

Result:
[image: Output]